# Get diagnostics from Github Packages backend when `dotnet nuget push` fails?

Tags: c#, nuget, github-package-registry

I am trying to port a legacy project to push nuget artifacts to Github Packages as a proof-of-concept, and learning on the job.

The push currently fails without an explanation:

```
C:\Users\m86194\source\repos\my-project>dotnet nuget push "**/*.nupkg" --source github  --skip-duplicate --api-key ***
Pushing my-project.1.0.0.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/me'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/me/
warn : No destination repository detected. Ensure the source project has a 'RepositoryUrl' property defined. If you're using a nuspec file, ensure that it has a repository element with the required 'type' and 'url' attributes.
  BadRequest https://nuget.pkg.github.com/me/ 4721ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```

(project and username changed by hand).  I understand that the warning given by dotnet locally about the RepositoryUrl is most likely correct even though it should be in there, but I would expect an explanatory rejection reason from the backend which I would like to see.

I did not notice such a debug log in my unexperienced browsing of the Github Packaging guides, and the help page for `dotnet nuget push` does not indicate a -v flag.

How do I get debug information from the server here?